# Why does Task.WhenAll return void?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, task

[image]

This is the code from the image above:

```
if (claims != null && claims.Any())
{
    // firstly, why doesn't this work?
    // var _claimResults = from claim in claims select UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, claim);

    // but this does...
    List<Task> _claimResults = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var claim in claims)
    {
        _claimResults.Add(UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, claim));   
    }

    // secondly, why does Task.WhenAll return void when it clearly says it returns Task?
    Task claimsResult = await Task.WhenAll(_claimResults);
}
```

1. Why doesn't the LINQ expression work, yet the foreach does.  The LINQ expression gives me a "underlying provider failed to open" exception on execution.
2. Why does Task.WhenAll() return void when it says it's return type is Task?

**Edit:** `claims` is a `List<Claim>` which I think is `List<System.Security.Claim>`.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll()` returns `Task` but when you `await` it, it returns void

Comment: When you `await` something, think of it as unwrapping the task into its return type. A `Task` (as opposed to `Task<T>`) does not have a return type. It's the Task equivalent of a void, basically. So, looking back at your code, you are awaiting a `Task`, unwrapping it into a void action, and attempting to assign that to a `Task` variable. That's not going to work. You *could* assign the resulting `Task` to the variable (without `await`) and *then* await the variable, if you wish.

Comment: change that LoC from `Task claimrResult = await Task.whenAll(_claimResults);` to just `await Task.whenAll(_claimResults);`

Comment: What is `claims`? I assume it's a queryable of some kind, so you try to run your query on whatever the provider is, instead of in memory. Try doing something like `claims.ToArray()` first (which you probably want to avoid querying multiple times anyway).

Answer (score 9):

`WhenAll` returns a `Task`, but then you're *awaiting* that task. Awaiting a plain `Task` (rather than a `Task<T>`) gives no result. So you either want:

```
Task claimsResult = Task.WhenAll(_claimResults);
```

or

```
await Task.WhenAll(_claimResults);
```

My suspicion is that the LINQ problem is because your `foreach` approach materializes the query immediately - the LINQ equivalent would be:

```
var _claimsResults = claims.Select(claim => UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, claim))
                           .ToList();
```

... where the `ToList()` method materializes the results immediately. (I've used the method call syntax rather than query expression syntax because query expressions are pretty pointless for trivial queries like this.)

Comment: Initially, I had just `await Task.WhenAll(_claimResults);` but it somehow caused a "null reference exception" despite the fact that the `_claimResults` array contained all tasks with a status of RanToCompletion.

Comment: @user1477388: Well we can't magically work out why that was happening without more information, but I hope you now understand why you're seeing the behaviour you reported in the question.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I do.  It was the `await Task.WhenAll(_claimR‌​esults);` that threw the exception, but I don't know how to investigate it further.  There is no inner exception.  Just figured I was using it wrongly.

Comment: @user1477388: Well, if you can create code that reproduces that problem in a minimal way, I suggest you put it in a new question (don't change this one).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about #1, but for #2 its because you called await on it

it should be

```
Task claimsResult = Task.WhenAll(_claimResults);
await claimsResult;
```

or omit the variable entirely if you don't need to delay the await somewhere else